# C# JSON serialization based on class definition

Tags: c#, json

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON.NET library, but run into following problem.

Dynamic serialization iterates over all object properties and fields. But when using eg ORM where dynamic proxying comes in, I've got obviously error that proxy internal fields can't be serialized.

Using attributes on serialized classes with OptIn approach is not an option. Classes are used not only for web app, and dependency for JSON.NET assemblies is not possible.

Any suggestion for approach with minimum binding/wiring code?

Comment: I'm guessing you are serializing for some kind of web service and while I'm sure you have good reasons for manual serialization, I would like to note that WCF response serializers (JSON as well) make use of the attributes defined in System.Runtime.Serialization (DataMember for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx). Using these you could define which things are serialized and how, of course if System.Runtime.Serialization would be an acceptable dependency for your classes.

Comment: Problem is, that I hardly can even change those classes (put something in them). It is part of bigger system other people maintaining so I have no control over it.

Comment: In such case you probably have no choice other than building a dedicated class set just for the service contract. I always used my homegrown mappers for Business<->Contract conversion, but nowadays you can use the Automapper, as Henrik suggests. T4 templates can help you generate your contract classes from originals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your json-format in a seperate set of classes and convert the ORM-classes to these with eg. [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).